# ternory operator giving error when used to show or hide a div react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to hide a div when it is in mobile view  i am using a ternory operator and i am getting error i cannot compltely hide the div becase it already has a ternory operator inside it how can i achive this

```
 {this.state.hidediv?
               (<div className="livechat">): (<div className="livechat2">)
                 } //error here 
                 {this.state.hidecaht ? (
                   <>
                     <a
                       href="#"
                       className="close"
                       onClick={() => this.hidechat(true)}
                     ></a>
                     <Livechat id={this.state.liveid} />
                   </>
                 ) : null}
               </div>
```

livechat2 has css display:none so it wont show up

img[image]

Comment: _"and i am getting error"_ - And that error is...? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [mcve]

Comment: Is the name of the property really `.hidecaht` and not `.hidechat`?

Comment: .hidecaht its correct

Comment: Please try doing ternory operation only for classname not for the div tag ```className={ this.state.hidediv ? "livechat":  "livechat2"}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you give an unclosed tag, try this:

```
<div className={this.state.hidediv ? "livechat" : "livechat2"}>
  {this.state.hidecaht &&
     <>
       <a
         href="#"
         className="close"
         onClick={() => this.hidechat(true)}
       ></a>
       <Livechat id={this.state.liveid} />
     </>
   }
</div>
```